Easy way to add a formatter to vscode extension if you already have a formatter tool?
I'm thinking of adding a formatter to the Grafana Alloy vscode extension: https://github.com/grafana/vscode-alloy/issues/3
This feels like it should be straightforward because alloy already provides a formatter with alloy fmt -w, so I thought running that command on save should be pretty straightforward. Instead, all of the formatting options in extensions for other languages are hundreds of lines of typescript. Am I missing something? I found this article from Microsoft, but the code in there looks very different from all of the other implementations I've seen on Github: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices
I'd love some guidance on this, as I've never written anything for vscode. Thanks!
